# How do I solve this problem using binomial theorem with square root in it?

Tags: binomial-theorem

The question is: Find the coefficient of $\frac{1}{x\sqrt x}$ in the expansion of $(x^2 - \frac{1}{2\sqrt x})^{18}$.

I have included a photo to make it easier to read because I do not know how to format the question.

Comment: One can rewrite your expression as $x^{36}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2x^2\sqrt{x}}\right)^{18}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Any term in the expansion would be of the form $${18\choose r} \cdot (x^2)^r \cdot\left(\frac 12 x^{-1/2}\right)^{18-r} $$ You need $x^{2r -\frac{18-r}{2}}=\frac{1}{x\sqrt x} =x^{-3/2}$ or $$2r-\frac{18-r}{2} =-\frac 32$$ Solve for $r$ from this equation and just plug its value in the first expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the binomial formula:
$$\biggl(x^2-\frac 1{2\sqrt x}\biggr)^{18}=\sum_{k=0}^{18}\binom{18}k x^{2k}\frac1{2^{18-k}x^{\tfrac{18-k}2}}$$
and determine $k$ such that $\;2k-\frac{18-k}2=-\frac 32$

Comment: @BarryCipra: Thank you for pointing them. I think I've corrected. Sometimes it's a bit hard to make the computations directly on typing…